# Adding a reset my password button to the user edit page

Tags: flask-appbuilder

The default behavior of FAB is to place the `Reset my password` button at the bottom of the `user/show/<pk>` page.
I want to have a `Reset my password` button also on my `user/edit/<pk>` page, is there a simple way to do that?